# VBA send mass mail with differedelivery time

Tags: excel, vba

What I tend to do is I have an excel sheet with list of staff and I wanted to send out a reminder with the detail in excel sheet. What I am trying to send an email out with DefferdDeliverytime option to park the email in outbox and deliver it later. With this code, I am able to send messages but what I don't know how to do is **to add a code to send and email with a specific send time according to the excel sheet.** Can anybody add a code for me to make it work.

```
Sub Mail_To_Friends()
    'Below Loop can be changed to While Loop or increase the limit (10) if your list has more than 10 mail ids
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim ToMSg As String
    Dim DueDate As String
    Dim AwardN As String
    Dim SendTime As String

    For i = 2 To 10
        SendTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 22)
        If SendTo <> "" Then
            ToMSg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 15)
            DueDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 14)
            AwardN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
            SendTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 22)
            Send_Mail SendTo, ToMSg, DueDate, AwardN, SendTime
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Sub Send_Mail(SendTo As String, ToMSg As String, DueDate As String, AwardN As String, SendTime As String)
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutlookMail
        .To = SendTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "draft report is due"
        .Body = "Dear " & ToMSg & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The following report is due to member on " & DueDate & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Award Name: " & AwardN
        .Display 'or just put .Send to directly send the mail instead of display
    End With

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You must describe the problem you encounter more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple as setting the DeferredDeliveryTime property on your MailItem.

```
With OutlookMail
    .To = SendTo
    .DeferredDeliveryTime = SendTime
    '... insert rest of your code here
End With
```

A few points to keep in mind; Firstly this property is a DateTime and your SendTime is a String. It *should* accept this assuming it is in a valid format ie. 18/05/2015. If you don't specify a Time, it will default to 00:00:00.
Secondly, this will keep the item in your Outbox on your local PC. So you must have Outlook open for it to actually send the e-mail at the specified time.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer. There is an error said. Run time error 440 The object does not support this method. The debug point to ".DeferredDeliveryTime = SendTime"

Comment: Can you give an example of what data is being passed in your SendTime variable?

Comment: here is the what is in the 5/19/2015  3:00:00 PM  Please see the link for the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97BzUn3O6m6OUV2cXZBVm5TSDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @Manop - I think it is a typo in your code. You have `.DefferedDeliveryTime = SendTime` when it should be `.DeferredDeliveryTime = SendTime`

Comment: @andshew Thank you on your kind respond and I am very appreciate that. Now my code work perfectly. I am pretty new to VBA and coding, I will be very thank full if you could guild me to format the email body as html. I do know HTML but need the first code to enable html.

Comment: @andshew, I am now able to implement html format in my email. Thank you for your support. Where should I mark this post as solved or I just leave it like this?

Comment: You should have an option next to the answer to select it as the answer. Glad to hear this is working.